# Grouping of a list's values into equal distance bins

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list:

```
long_list = []
for i in range(100):
    long_list.append(i)
```

I'm trying to create a function that takes that list, and a number of bins, and outputs a new list where every value is changed to the closest bin value. The bins need to be equally distanced from the min value of the list, to the max value.

So in the example above, if `bins=6`, the function will find 6 bin values `[0,20,40,60,80,100]`, and output a new list:

```
new_list=[0,0,0,0...20,20,20...40,40...]
```

I was thinking about something like this:

```
def list_grouper(long_list, bins_number):
    '''outputs new list'''
```

Update:
Solved it thanks to @Chris M-B

```
def list_grouper(long_list, bins_number):
    bins = np.linspace(min(long_list), max(long_list), bins_number)
    bins_idx = np.digitize(long_list, bins)
    bins_idx = bins_idx -1 
    
    for idx in range(len(long_list)):
        long_list[idx] = bins[bins_idx[idx]]
        
    return long_list
list_grouper(list(range(10)), 3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is a combination of numpy.linspace (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) and numpy.digitize (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html).  You can get the bin edges using np.linspace(), then use those bin edges in np.digitize(), which will return the bin indices for the given values.