# Grouping of a list of lists values into equal distance bins

Tags: python, list

Following [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65498237/grouping-of-a-lists-values-into-equal-distance-bins) I managed to group 1 list values into equal distance bins:

```
y = list(range(100))
def list_grouper(long_list, bins_number):
    bins = np.linspace(min(long_list), max(long_list), bins_number)
    bins_idx = np.digitize(long_list, bins)
    bins_idx = bins_idx -1 
    
    return bins_idx    
    
list_grouper(y, 20)

>>>array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  3,
        3,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  6,  6,
        6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9,  9,
        9,  9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
       13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16,
       16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19])
```

Is there a way to do the same thing but over a list of lists?

```
list_of_lists = [list(range(20)), list(range(10, 40)), list(range(40, 60))]
```

Such that all of the values (from all the lists) will be considered when dividing into equal distances (rather than each list's values separately), but each list will still be separate?
e.g.

```
list_of_lists_output = [[0,0,0,0,1,1,1...], [5,5...], [8...]]
```

**Update**:
@Giacomo method almost works. It works if the lists have the same number of values. Otherwise I'm getting these 2 errors:

```
list_of_lists = [list(range(20)), list(range(10, 40)), list(range(40, 60))]
list_of_lists = np.array(list_of_lists)
list_grouper2(list_of_lists, 5)

>>>ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

Or this:

```
list_of_lists = [list(range(20)), list(range(10, 40))]
list_of_lists = np.array(list_of_lists)
list_grouper2(list_of_lists, 5)
>>>ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (30,) (20,)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this should work *only for arrays of definite shape*

```
list_grouper(long_list, bins_number):

   temp = long_list.reshape(-1)
   bins = np.linspace(min(temp), max(temp), bins_number)
   bins_idx = np.digitize(long_list, bins)
   bins_idx = bins_idx -1 

   return bins_idx 

list_of_lists = np.array([list(range(20)), list(range(20,40))]) #shape (2,20)
one_lists = np.array([list(range(20))])

print("List of lists:")
print(list_grouper(list_of_lists, 20))

#List of lists:
#[[ 0  0  0  1  1  2  2  3  3  4  4  5  5  6  6  7  7  8  8  9]
#[ 9 10 10 11 11 12 12 13 13 14 14 15 15 16 16 17 17 18 18 19]]

print("One list:")
print(list_grouper(one_lists, 20))

#One list:
#[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]]
```

When dealing with variable size array a general solution could be

```
def list_grouper(long_list, bins_number):

   temp = np.concatenate(long_list, axis=0)
   bins = np.linspace(min(temp), max(temp), bins_number)

   toret = [np.digitize(i, bins) -1 for i in long_list]

   return toret  

list_of_lists = np.array([list(range(20)), list(range(20,60)), 
                              list(range(90,100))])
print(list_grouper(list_of_lists, 20))

#[array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]), array([ 3,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,
#    7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9, 10,
#   10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11]), array([17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19])]
```

Hope that does finally work!

Comment: Thanks for the help! Please see my update! I feel like this is very close

Comment: @Penguin Edited my answer, check if it now works!

Comment: Perfect! This seems to work. Thanks a lot